# How to generate memory dump from outside a running container

Tags: memory, container, dump

I have running a .net service inside a container. And I am observing the memory consumption of this service inside the container is gradually going up to the limit set to that container and after it reaches the threshold limit the container get killed. To debug further I want to generate a memory dump of the .net service inside the container by staying outside the container. Can I do it?
I have refrained to install any third-party software as the policy is not allowing me.

My current host details are as follows,

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
```

but I have `Ulimit` installed on the host machine. Tried with Ulimit but not successful.

Comment: What container technology are you using - docker, lxc, ??? Are you after a `core file` or do you literally want a copy of the memory?

Comment: Yeah docker, lxc with image type is alpine. I am after the coredump

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out, I used `GNU Debugger` or `gdb` for generating the core sump for a container from outside the container,

1. "sudo docker ps -a | grep service_container_name"  to get the
   container id.
2. "sudo docker inspect [container id] | more" to get the parent PID
3. "pstree -pg [parent pid]"  to get the child PID
4. "sudo ps -aux | grep [child pid]"
5. "sudo gcore PID"